# Detecting Currently running App. Android

Tags: android, android-service

I am using Following code to detect currently running app . But when I am running any new app.  I am not getting it's package name, It is toasting "com.hedy.launcher".
Whats wrong with the code ?

```
 @Override
          public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onStartCommand(intent, flags,startId);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Service running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                handler = new Handler(){

                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                       // count=count+1;
                       // Toast.makeText(MyService.this, ""+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, ""+packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                };



                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    while(true)
                    {
                       try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                    }

                                    }
                }).start();
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: com.hedy.launcher looks like a package name. What are you expecting?

Comment: @shiladitya I am running Adobe reader so I want name of package related to Adobe reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

This is the line where you are extracting package name. 
Try to increase the maxNum parameter(you have set to 1).

am.getRunningTasks(maxNum) will return an arraylist. check all the contents of arraylist to see whether you are getting you required item in any of them

Comment: It worked thanks. Now if i want to kill some background app how can I do that.

Comment: i dont think you can kill them unless you have root access, because all applications in android are sandboxed.

Comment: there is application stay focused which is able to kill other applications I would like to know how is it working there...